# Java Selenium Webdriver set Volume?

Tags: java, selenium, audio, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Hello I have been looking for a while now but I can't seem to find a way to do this maybe it does not exist?

I have a java app that use selenium to open a music player from website. Problem is the player from the website have the sound at max everytime i open it, I would like to be able to set the volume to half or something.

Now I have seen some people talk about dragging the slider of the player but in this case I can't seem to be able to get the xpath of the player, maybe because it is a player that is embed.

So what I am looking for is a way to change the windows sound that is linked to the new window created by the Webdriver.

Any help would be amazing !

( the player : [link](http://songily.com/sc/file/71903177.mp3) if someone wants to check the xpath or whatever )

Comment: Getting 403 Forbibben while following the link.

Comment: oh yeah i forgot the link get redirected [try this](http://songily.com/sc/file/71903177.mp3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to locate the `audio` tag and set the [`volume`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio#Attributes) property through javascript:

> volume
>
> The playback volume of any audio portions, in the range 0.0
>   (silent) to 1.0 (loudest).

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.tagName("audio")));

if (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].volume = 0.5;", element);
}
```

Comment: Seemed like what i needed but : Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element

Comment: @Sadistik okay, updated. You need to wait for the `audio` element to be present.

Comment: Problem is if you go to the page i linked and try the javascript console there is no way to actually retreive the player. tagName should be video but that is not working, and it has a name i tried that also and no avail. Edit : btw thank you for your answer

Comment: Okay so i find the element it would seem but i get : unknown error: element is not defined

Comment: @Sadistik The JavaScript should be `"arguments[0].volume = 0.5"`. alecxe has momentarily forgotten how arguments are passed to the JavaScript side.